# How to transfer SQL spatial result to C# application?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a table(TEST) that contain some events, dates of events and qty of peoples on this event.

```
   Dat      |   Event      |  Qty
2012-30-08    SomeEvent1       5
2012-09-06    SomeEvent2      10
2012-09-18    SomeEvent3       7
2012-09-29    SomeEvent4       1
2012-10-03    SomeEvent5       2
```

I have built a graphical representation of the content of this table. On X-axis I show my timeline - from first date to last date.
Circles on X-axis indicates qty of people on current event (radius of circle = qty of peoples). 
Here my query and spatial result:

```
DECLARE @FIRST_DATE DATE
DECLARE @LAST_DATE DATE
SET @FIRST_DATE = (SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM [DATABSE_TEST].dbo.TEST)
SET @LAST_DATE = (SELECT MIN([Date]) FROM [DATABSE_TEST].dbo.TEST)

--TIMELINE Build my timeline
DECLARE @SQL_TIMELINE VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL_TIMELINE = 'SELECT geometry::STPolyFromText(''POLYGON((0 -0.1, 0 0.1,' + CAST(DATEDIFF(DD, @LAST_DATE,     @FIRST_DATE) AS VARCHAR) + ' 0.1, ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(DD, @LAST_DATE, @FIRST_DATE) AS VARCHAR) + ' -0.1, 0 -0.1))'', 0) AS DRAWING' 

--CIRCLES
DECLARE @SQL_CIRCLES VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

--POINTS Array of points
DECLARE @POINTS VARCHAR(MAX)

--DATE Date of current event
DECLARE @DATE DATE

--RADIUS = qty of peoples
DECLARE @RADIUS FLOAT

--X,Y coordinates of current circle
DECLARE @X_COORD FLOAT
DECLARE @Y_COORD FLOAT
DECLARE @DEGREE INT = 0


DECLARE CUR CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT [Date], Qty FROM [DATABSE_TEST].dbo.TEST
OPEN CUR
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @DATE, @RADIUS
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
        SET @POINTS = ''
        SET @DEGREE = 0
        WHILE (@DEGREE <= 360)
            BEGIN
            --Find circle coordinates
            SET @X_COORD = DATEDIFF(DD, @LAST_DATE, @DATE) + @RADIUS * COS(@DEGREE*PI()/180)
            SET @Y_COORD = 0 + @RADIUS * SIN(@DEGREE*PI()/180)
            --Build poinrs array            
            SET @POINTS = @POINTS + CAST(@X_COORD AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST(@Y_COORD AS VARCHAR) + ', '
            SET @DEGREE = @DEGREE + 10      
        END 
        --Build query: points coordinates + last point SUBSTRING(@POINTS, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @POINTS)) - tha same as first point in @POINTS to close POLYGON
        SET @SQL_CIRCLES = @SQL_CIRCLES + ' UNION ALL SELECT geometry::STPolyFromText(''POLYGON((' + @POINTS + SUBSTRING(@POINTS, 0, CHARINDEX(',', @POINTS)) + '))'',0) AS DRAWING'        
        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @DATE, @RADIUS 
        END  
CLOSE CUR 
DEALLOCATE CUR 
--Execute query
EXEC(@SQL_TIMELINE + @SQL_CIRCLES)
```

[image]

[image]

How can I pass spatial result to C# application? I want to show this image in my application, but not sure how to correctly transfer it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .Net framework 4.5 then it has a type [DbGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeometry.aspx) and [DbGeography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.aspx) that can be used to hold spatial data. These classes are available under [System.Data.Spatial Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.aspx).

But if you are working with earlier versions of .Net framework then you can get the geometries from the SQL server [`AS_Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933977.aspx) which will return you WKT of the object, that can be used in your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using .Net framework 3.5. `As_text` method applicable for geometry data type variables. I should change my query for this method implementation. Thanks, I will try.

Comment: You are welcome, if you are using .Net 3.5 then its better if you return WKT from your SQL server and then process that in C#, ST_AsText works on Geometry as well as Geography type of SQL Server